# why is this code not targeting the right selector

Tags: javascript, jquery

This function is supposed to change the background color of the object being clicked

```
function colorMe(){
   $(this).css('background-color', 'red');
}
```

I call it like this

```
$('.colorme').click(colorMe);
```

and it changes the background of this div

```
<div class="colorme">Color Me</div>
```

The problem is that I want to do something else before running colorMe. So I can't use just `$('.colorme').click(colorMe);`. What I'm trying to do is something like this

```
$('.colorme').click(function(){
  alert('something happens first, then colorMe is called');
  colorMe();         //I call colorMe here..
  $(this).colorMe(); //I also tried this, but it's not working
});
```

but it's not affecting the div. I think it lost track of the div to affect. Do I need to pass it and how?

Comment: did you try to put this line : $(this).css('background-color', 'red');
 in the click function , instead of standalone function

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
function colorMe(elt){
   $(elt).css('background-color', 'red');
}

$('.colorme').click(function(){
  alert('something happens first, then colorMe is called');
  colorMe(this);         //I call colorMe here..
});
```

To call a function on a jQuery object like you did here

```
$(this).colorMe()
```

you would have to build a plugin (I edited it to add a class)

```
// css
.red {
    background: red;
}

// js
(function($) {
    $.fn.extend({
        colorMe: function() {
            this.addClass("red");
        },
        unColorMe: function() {
            this.removeClass("red");
        }
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Then you would be able to do

```
$(".a_class").colorMe();
$(".a_class").unColorMe();
```

Comment: Good answer, Robin, and explaining the plugin. I would also second JK's opinion that using a class is better than inlining the style.

Comment: +1 But NB that the call to `each` is unnecessary, as `$.fn.css` contains one itself.

Comment: I changed the plugin to add a class, removed the unnecessary loop and added unColorMe.

Answer (score 3):

You should use the `.addClass()` method.

```
function colorMe(element){
   element.addClass('my-red-class');
}

$('.colorme').click(function(){      
  colorMe(this);         
});
```

And in your css file you have a class called 'my-red-class' (use a better name!)

```
.my-red-class { background-color: red; }
```

And you can also easily remove the css:

```
function unColorMe(element){
   element.removeClass('my-red-class');
}
```

Comment: Your scope is wrong: the `click` callback will be passed a DOM Element, not a jQuery object; DOM elements do not have an `addClass()` method.

Answer (score 1):

```
function colorMe(){
    $(this).css('color', 'red');
}
```

using call()

```
$('.colorme').click(function(){
    alert('something happens first, then colorMe is called');
    colorMe.call(this);
});
```